# convertir numeros de un ciclo for a elementos de un array

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

tengo el siguiente codigo y quiere poder poner todos los numero que sean divisible entre 3 en un parrafo, los que sean divisibles entre 5 en otro, pero no logro hacerlo.

```js
let uno = document.getElementById("uno");
let dos = document.getElementById("dos");
var tres;

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { 
    if(i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0){
        document.write("fizzbuzz");
    }
    else if(i % 3 == 0){
        tres =  i
        document.write("fizz ");
    }
    else if(i % 5 == 0){
        document.write("buzz ");
    }

    document.write(i+"<br>")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>numeros divisibles en 3:</p> 
    <p id="uno"></p>

    <p>numeros divisibles en 5:</p> 
    <p id="dos"></p>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer. Está comentado para que entiendas todo. Una pequeña aclaracion, desde mi punto de vista estaba mal el "else" ya que tienes que tener en cuenta que hay numeros que son divisibles entre 3 y 5, otros entre 2 y 3 etc... entonces en ese caso como el 6 por ejemplo, vas a ingresarlo en el contenedor 2 y en el 3 ya no vas a verificar cuando corresponde que vaya ahí también. No se si es la idea... Espero que te sirva, saludos!

```js
  // vamos a seleccionar el contador de los numeros divisibles por 2
    var contenedorDos = document.getElementById("dos");
    // vamos a seleccionar el contador de los numeros divisibles por 5
    var contenedorTres = document.getElementById("tres");
     // vamos a seleccionar el contador de los numeros divisibles por 3
    var contenedorCinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
    //En las siguientes variables, vamos a ir concatenando los números que correspondan.
    var textoDos=""; 
    var textoTres="";
    var textoCinco="";

    for(let i = 1; i<100; i++){
      // el resto de la division es igual a cero? entonces es divisible.
      if(i%2===0){
      // A lo que ya tengo en el contenedor, le voy a agregar el valor de i.
      textoDos = textoDos +"/ "+i;
      }
      if(i%3===0){
      // el resto de la division es igual a cero? entonces es divisible.
      textoTres = textoTres +"/ "+i; //uso "/" como separador, lo puedes cambiar
      }
      if(i%5===0){
      // el resto de la division es igual a cero? entonces es divisible.
        textoCinco = textoCinco +"/ "+i;
      }
    }
    // una vez que terminamos de recorrer nuestro for, le vamos a indicar el contenido de nuestros divs/contenedores usando la propuedad "textContent"
    contenedorDos.textContent = textoDos;
    contenedorTres.textContent = textoTres;
    contenedorCinco.textContent = textoCinco;
```

```html
  <h5>Numeros divisibles en 2:</h5> 
    <div id="dos"></div>
<h5>Numeros divisibles en 3:</h5> 
    <div id="tres"></div>
    <h5>Numeros divisibles en 5:</h5> 
    <div id="cinco"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear 2 variables como arreglos **tres** y **cinco** en el **for** las condiciones que tienes ya están bien solo es corregir un poco el contenido de las mismas. Por ejemplo 
Cuando entre en 3

tres.push(i)

Cuando entre en 5

cinco.push(i)

Así cuando termine el ciclo ya tendrás 2 arreglos con los números que necesitas ya solo es usar otro **for** para imprimir cada numero en un **ul** por ejemplo.

```
<li>tres[i]</li>
```

Y en otro ul hacer lo mismo

```
<li>cinco[i]</li>
```

Y es todo, asi tienes las listas de los numeros divisibles entre 3 y 5